# Undefined Reference to (both object variables and base variables), C++ AVR

Tags: c++, makefile, winavr

IntermediateRobotFunctions.cpp:

```
 /*
 * IntermediateRobotFunctions.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 27 Mar 2015
 *      Author: Edward
 */

#include "IntermediateRobotFunctions.hpp"

IntermediateRobotFunctions::IntermediateRobotFunctions() {
    block = Block::Block();
    robot = Robot::Robot();
    basic = BasicRobotFunctions::BasicRobotFunctions();
    carrying = false;
}

IntermediateRobotFunctions::IntermediateRobotFunctions(Robot R,Block B) {
    block = B;
    robot = R;
    basic = BasicRobotFunctions::BasicRobotFunctions(R);
    carrying = false;
}

IntermediateRobotFunctions::~IntermediateRobotFunctions() {}

void IntermediateRobotFunctions::PickUp(Robot R, Block B){
    if(R.getCarrying()==false){
        Walk(R);
        basic.MoveChest();
        basic.MoveArm(1);
        basic.MoveArm(2);
        basic.MoveChest();
        R.setCarrying(true);
        carrying = true;
    }
    else{
        PutDown(R);
        PickUp(R,B);
    }
}

void IntermediateRobotFunctions::PutDown(Robot R){
    if(R.getCarrying()==true){
        basic.MoveChest();
        basic.MoveArm(1);
        basic.MoveArm(2);
        basic.MoveChest();
        R.setCarrying(false);
        carrying = false;
    }
}

//TODO to test
Block IntermediateRobotFunctions::newNearest(){
    Block B,B1;
    B1 = Block::Block();
    for(int i = 0; i<360; i++){
        basic.Turn(1);
        if(dxl_read_word(100,32)>0){
            B = Block::Block();
            B.setDistance(dxl_read_word(100,27));
            B.setBrightness(dxl_read_word(100,30));
            B.setGrounded(true);
        }
        if(B.getDistance() <= B1.getDistance()){
            B1 = B;
        }
    }
    return B1;
}

Robot IntermediateRobotFunctions::updateRobotData(){
    Block block;
    bool carry = carrying;
    block = newNearest(robot);
    Robot R = Robot(block,carry);
    return R;
}

//TODO to test
void IntermediateRobotFunctions::Walk(Robot R){
    int steps = basic.CalculateSteps();
    while(dxl_read_word(100,32)<=0)
        basic.Turn(1);
    for(int i =0;i<steps;i++){
        basic.Step(1);
        basic.Step(2);
    }
}
```

IntermediateRobotFunctions.hpp:

```
/*
 * IntermediateRobotFunctions.hpp
 *
 *  Created on: 27 Mar 2015
 *      Author: Edward
 */

#ifndef INTERMEDIATEROBOTFUNCTIONS_HPP_
#define INTERMEDIATEROBOTFUNCTIONS_HPP_

#include "typedefinitions.h"
#include "Robot.hpp"
#include "Block.hpp"
#include "BasicRobotFunctions.hpp"

class IntermediateRobotFunctions {
public:
    static Block block;
    static Robot robot;
    static BasicRobotFunctions basic;
    static bool carrying;
    //pos position;
    static void PickUp(Robot R, Block B);
    static void PutDown(Robot R);
    static void Walk(Robot R);
    static Block newNearest(Robot R);
    static Block newNearest();
    static Robot updateRobotData();
    IntermediateRobotFunctions();
    IntermediateRobotFunctions(Robot R,Block B);
    virtual ~IntermediateRobotFunctions();
};

#endif /* INTERMEDIATEROBOTFUNCTIONS_HPP_ */
```

Makefile:

```
# Hey Emacs, this is a -*- makefile -*-
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WinAVR Makefile Template written by Eric B. Weddington, Jörg Wunsch, et al.
#
# Released to the Public Domain
#
# Additional material for this makefile was written by:
# Peter Fleury
# Tim Henigan
# Colin O'Flynn
# Reiner Patommel
# Markus Pfaff
# Sander Pool
# Frederik Rouleau
# Carlos Lamas
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# On command line:
#
# make all = Make software.
#
# make clean = Clean out built project files.
#
# make coff = Convert ELF to AVR COFF.
#
# make extcoff = Convert ELF to AVR Extended COFF.
#
# make program = Download the hex file to the device, using avrdude.
#                Please customize the avrdude settings below first!
#
# make debug = Start either simulavr or avarice as specified for debugging, 
#              with avr-gdb or avr-insight as the front end for debugging.
#
# make filename.s = Just compile filename.c into the assembler code only.
#
# make filename.i = Create a preprocessed source file for use in submitting
#                   bug reports to the GCC project.
#
# To rebuild project do "make clean" then "make all".
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------


# MCU name
MCU = atmega128


# Processor frequency.
#     This will define a symbol, F_CPU, in all source code files equal to the 
#     processor frequency. You can then use this symbol in your source code to 
#     calculate timings. Do NOT tack on a 'UL' at the end, this will be done
#     automatically to create a 32-bit value in your source code.
#     Typical values are:
#         F_CPU =  1000000
#         F_CPU =  1843200
#         F_CPU =  2000000
#         F_CPU =  3686400
#         F_CPU =  4000000
#         F_CPU =  7372800
#         F_CPU =  8000000
#         F_CPU = 11059200
#         F_CPU = 14745600
#         F_CPU = 16000000
#         F_CPU = 18432000
#         F_CPU = 20000000
F_CPU = 16000000


# Output format. (can be srec, ihex, binary)
FORMAT = ihex


# Target file name (without extension).
TARGET = main


# Object files directory
#     To put object files in current directory, use a dot (.), do NOT make
#     this an empty or blank macro!
OBJDIR = .


# List C source files here. (C dependencies are automatically generated.)
SRC =


# List C++ source files here. (C dependencies are automatically generated.)
CPPSRC = $(TARGET).cpp AdvancedRobotFunctions.cpp IntermediateRobotFunctions.cpp BasicRobotFunctions.cpp Robot.cpp Block.cpp Structure.cpp 


# List Assembler source files here.
#     Make them always end in a capital .S.  Files ending in a lowercase .s
#     will not be considered source files but generated files (assembler
#     output from the compiler), and will be deleted upon "make clean"!
#     Even though the DOS/Win* filesystem matches both .s and .S the same,
#     it will preserve the spelling of the filenames, and gcc itself does
#     care about how the name is spelled on its command-line.
ASRC =


# Optimization level, can be [0, 1, 2, 3, s]. 
#     0 = turn off optimization. s = optimize for size.
#     (Note: 3 is not always the best optimization level. See avr-libc FAQ.)
OPT = s


# Debugging format.
#     Native formats for AVR-GCC's -g are dwarf-2 [default] or stabs.
#     AVR Studio 4.10 requires dwarf-2.
#     AVR [Extended] COFF format requires stabs, plus an avr-objcopy run.
DEBUG = dwarf-2


# List any extra directories to look for include files here.
#     Each directory must be seperated by a space.
#     Use forward slashes for directory separators.
#     For a directory that has spaces, enclose it in quotes.
EXTRAINCDIRS = 


# Compiler flag to set the C Standard level.
#     c89   = "ANSI" C
#     gnu89 = c89 plus GCC extensions
#     c99   = ISO C99 standard (not yet fully implemented)
#     gnu99 = c99 plus GCC extensions
CSTANDARD = -std=gnu99


# Place -D or -U options here for C sources
CDEFS = -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)UL


# Place -D or -U options here for ASM sources
ADEFS = -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)


# Place -D or -U options here for C++ sources
CPPDEFS = -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)UL
#CPPDEFS += -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#CPPDEFS += -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS



#---------------- Compiler Options C ----------------
#  -g*:          generate debugging information
#  -O*:          optimization level
#  -f...:        tuning, see GCC manual and avr-libc documentation
#  -Wall...:     warning level
#  -Wa,...:      tell GCC to pass this to the assembler.
#    -adhlns...: create assembler listing
CFLAGS = -g$(DEBUG)
CFLAGS += $(CDEFS)
CFLAGS += -O$(OPT)
CFLAGS += -funsigned-char
CFLAGS += -funsigned-bitfields
CFLAGS += -fpack-struct
CFLAGS += -fshort-enums
CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes
#CFLAGS += -mshort-calls
#CFLAGS += -fno-unit-at-a-time
#CFLAGS += -Wundef
#CFLAGS += -Wunreachable-code
#CFLAGS += -Wsign-compare
CFLAGS += -Wa,-adhlns=$(<:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst)
CFLAGS += $(patsubst %,-I%,$(EXTRAINCDIRS))
CFLAGS += $(CSTANDARD)


#---------------- Compiler Options C++ ----------------
#  -g*:          generate debugging information
#  -O*:          optimization level
#  -f...:        tuning, see GCC manual and avr-libc documentation
#  -Wall...:     warning level
#  -Wa,...:      tell GCC to pass this to the assembler.
#    -adhlns...: create assembler listing
CPPFLAGS = -g$(DEBUG)
CPPFLAGS += $(CPPDEFS)
CPPFLAGS += -O$(OPT)
CPPFLAGS += -funsigned-char
CPPFLAGS += -funsigned-bitfields
CPPFLAGS += -fpack-struct
CPPFLAGS += -fshort-enums
CPPFLAGS += -fno-exceptions
CPPFLAGS += -Wall
CPPFLAGS += -Wundef
#CPPFLAGS += -mshort-calls
#CPPFLAGS += -fno-unit-at-a-time
#CPPFLAGS += -Wstrict-prototypes
#CPPFLAGS += -Wunreachable-code
#CPPFLAGS += -Wsign-compare
CPPFLAGS += -Wa,-adhlns=$(<:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst)
CPPFLAGS += $(patsubst %,-I%,$(EXTRAINCDIRS))
CPPFLAGS += $(CSTANDARD)


#---------------- Assembler Options ----------------
#  -Wa,...:   tell GCC to pass this to the assembler.
#  -adhlns:   create listing
#  -gstabs:   have the assembler create line number information; note that
#             for use in COFF files, additional information about filenames
#             and function names needs to be present in the assembler source
#             files -- see avr-libc docs [FIXME: not yet described there]
#  -listing-cont-lines: Sets the maximum number of continuation lines of hex 
#       dump that will be displayed for a given single line of source input.
ASFLAGS = $(ADEFS) -Wa,-adhlns=$(<:%.S=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst),-gstabs,--listing-cont-lines=100


#---------------- Library Options ----------------
# Minimalistic printf version
PRINTF_LIB_MIN = -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

# Floating point printf version (requires MATH_LIB = -lm below)
PRINTF_LIB_FLOAT = -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt

# If this is left blank, then it will use the Standard printf version.
PRINTF_LIB = 
#PRINTF_LIB = $(PRINTF_LIB_MIN)
#PRINTF_LIB = $(PRINTF_LIB_FLOAT)


# Minimalistic scanf version
SCANF_LIB_MIN = -Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

# Floating point + %[ scanf version (requires MATH_LIB = -lm below)
SCANF_LIB_FLOAT = -Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt

# If this is left blank, then it will use the Standard scanf version.
SCANF_LIB = 
#SCANF_LIB = $(SCANF_LIB_MIN)
#SCANF_LIB = $(SCANF_LIB_FLOAT)


MATH_LIB = -lm


# List any extra directories to look for libraries here.
#     Each directory must be seperated by a space.
#     Use forward slashes for directory separators.
#     For a directory that has spaces, enclose it in quotes.
EXTRALIBDIRS = 



#---------------- External Memory Options ----------------

# 64 KB of external RAM, starting after internal RAM (ATmega128!),
# used for variables (.data/.bss) and heap (malloc()).
#EXTMEMOPTS = -Wl,-Tdata=0x801100,--defsym=__heap_end=0x80ffff

# 64 KB of external RAM, starting after internal RAM (ATmega128!),
# only used for heap (malloc()).
#EXTMEMOPTS = -Wl,--section-start,.data=0x801100,--defsym=__heap_end=0x80ffff

EXTMEMOPTS = 



#---------------- Linker Options ----------------
#  -Wl,...:     tell GCC to pass this to linker.
#    -Map:      create map file
#    --cref:    add cross reference to  map file
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map,--cref
LDFLAGS += $(EXTMEMOPTS)
LDFLAGS += $(patsubst %,-L%,$(EXTRALIBDIRS))
LDFLAGS += $(PRINTF_LIB) $(SCANF_LIB) $(MATH_LIB)
#LDFLAGS += -T linker_script.x



#---------------- Programming Options (avrdude) ----------------

# Programming hardware
# Type: avrdude -c ?
# to get a full listing.
#
AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER = stk500v2

# com1 = serial port. Use lpt1 to connect to parallel port.
AVRDUDE_PORT = com3    # programmer connected to serial device

AVRDUDE_WRITE_FLASH = -U flash:w:$(TARGET).hex
#AVRDUDE_WRITE_EEPROM = -U eeprom:w:$(TARGET).eep


# Uncomment the following if you want avrdude's erase cycle counter.
# Note that this counter needs to be initialized first using -Yn,
# see avrdude manual.
#AVRDUDE_ERASE_COUNTER = -y

# Uncomment the following if you do /not/ wish a verification to be
# performed after programming the device.
#AVRDUDE_NO_VERIFY = -V

# Increase verbosity level.  Please use this when submitting bug
# reports about avrdude. See <http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/avrdude> 
# to submit bug reports.
#AVRDUDE_VERBOSE = -v -v

AVRDUDE_FLAGS = -p $(MCU) -P $(AVRDUDE_PORT) -c $(AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER)
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += $(AVRDUDE_NO_VERIFY)
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += $(AVRDUDE_VERBOSE)
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += $(AVRDUDE_ERASE_COUNTER)



#---------------- Debugging Options ----------------

# For simulavr only - target MCU frequency.
DEBUG_MFREQ = $(F_CPU)

# Set the DEBUG_UI to either gdb or insight.
# DEBUG_UI = gdb
DEBUG_UI = insight

# Set the debugging back-end to either avarice, simulavr.
DEBUG_BACKEND = avarice
#DEBUG_BACKEND = simulavr

# GDB Init Filename.
GDBINIT_FILE = __avr_gdbinit

# When using avarice settings for the JTAG
JTAG_DEV = /dev/com1

# Debugging port used to communicate between GDB / avarice / simulavr.
DEBUG_PORT = 4242

# Debugging host used to communicate between GDB / avarice / simulavr, normally
#     just set to localhost unless doing some sort of crazy debugging when 
#     avarice is running on a different computer.
DEBUG_HOST = localhost



#============================================================================


# Define programs and commands.
SHELL = sh
CC = avr-gcc
OBJCOPY = avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP = avr-objdump
SIZE = avr-size
AR = avr-ar rcs
NM = avr-nm
AVRDUDE = avrdude
REMOVE = rm -f
REMOVEDIR = rm -rf
COPY = cp
WINSHELL = cmd


# Define Messages
# English
MSG_ERRORS_NONE = Errors: none
MSG_BEGIN = -------- begin --------
MSG_END = --------  end  --------
MSG_SIZE_BEFORE = Size before: 
MSG_SIZE_AFTER = Size after:
MSG_COFF = Converting to AVR COFF:
MSG_EXTENDED_COFF = Converting to AVR Extended COFF:
MSG_FLASH = Creating load file for Flash:
MSG_EEPROM = Creating load file for EEPROM:
MSG_EXTENDED_LISTING = Creating Extended Listing:
MSG_SYMBOL_TABLE = Creating Symbol Table:
MSG_LINKING = Linking:
MSG_COMPILING = Compiling C:
MSG_COMPILING_CPP = Compiling C++:
MSG_ASSEMBLING = Assembling:
MSG_CLEANING = Cleaning project:
MSG_CREATING_LIBRARY = Creating library:




# Define all object files.
OBJ = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) $(CPPSRC:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) $(ASRC:%.S=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) 

# Define all listing files.
LST = $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst) $(CPPSRC:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst) $(ASRC:%.S=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst) 


# Compiler flags to generate dependency files.
GENDEPFLAGS = -MMD -MP -MF .dep/$(@F).d


# Combine all necessary flags and optional flags.
# Add target processor to flags.
ALL_CFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. $(CFLAGS) $(GENDEPFLAGS)
ALL_CPPFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. -x c++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(GENDEPFLAGS)
ALL_ASFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. -x assembler-with-cpp $(ASFLAGS)





# Default target.
all: begin gccversion sizebefore build sizeafter end

# Change the build target to build a HEX file or a library.
build: elf hex eep lss sym
#build: lib


elf: $(TARGET).elf
hex: $(TARGET).hex
eep: $(TARGET).eep
lss: $(TARGET).lss
sym: $(TARGET).sym
LIBNAME=lib$(TARGET).a
lib: $(LIBNAME)



# Eye candy.
# AVR Studio 3.x does not check make's exit code but relies on
# the following magic strings to be generated by the compile job.
begin:
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_BEGIN)

end:
    @echo $(MSG_END)
    @echo


# Display size of file.
HEXSIZE = $(SIZE) --target=$(FORMAT) $(TARGET).hex
ELFSIZE = $(SIZE) --mcu=$(MCU) --format=avr $(TARGET).elf

sizebefore:
    @if test -f $(TARGET).elf; then echo; echo $(MSG_SIZE_BEFORE); $(ELFSIZE); \
    2>/dev/null; echo; fi

sizeafter:
    @if test -f $(TARGET).elf; then echo; echo $(MSG_SIZE_AFTER); $(ELFSIZE); \
    2>/dev/null; echo; fi



# Display compiler version information.
gccversion : 
    @$(CC) --version



# Program the device.  
program: $(TARGET).hex $(TARGET).eep
    $(AVRDUDE) $(AVRDUDE_FLAGS) $(AVRDUDE_WRITE_FLASH) $(AVRDUDE_WRITE_EEPROM)


# Generate avr-gdb config/init file which does the following:
#     define the reset signal, load the target file, connect to target, and set 
#     a breakpoint at main().
gdb-config: 
    @$(REMOVE) $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo define reset >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo SIGNAL SIGHUP >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo end >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo file $(TARGET).elf >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo target remote $(DEBUG_HOST):$(DEBUG_PORT)  >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
ifeq ($(DEBUG_BACKEND),simulavr)
    @echo load  >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
endif
    @echo break main >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)

debug: gdb-config $(TARGET).elf
ifeq ($(DEBUG_BACKEND), avarice)
    @echo Starting AVaRICE - Press enter when "waiting to connect" message displays.
    @$(WINSHELL) /c start avarice --jtag $(JTAG_DEV) --erase --program --file \
    $(TARGET).elf $(DEBUG_HOST):$(DEBUG_PORT)
    @$(WINSHELL) /c pause

else
    @$(WINSHELL) /c start simulavr --gdbserver --device $(MCU) --clock-freq \
    $(DEBUG_MFREQ) --port $(DEBUG_PORT)
endif
    @$(WINSHELL) /c start avr-$(DEBUG_UI) --command=$(GDBINIT_FILE)




# Convert ELF to COFF for use in debugging / simulating in AVR Studio or VMLAB.
COFFCONVERT = $(OBJCOPY) --debugging
COFFCONVERT += --change-section-address .data-0x800000
COFFCONVERT += --change-section-address .bss-0x800000
COFFCONVERT += --change-section-address .noinit-0x800000
COFFCONVERT += --change-section-address .eeprom-0x810000



coff: $(TARGET).elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_COFF) $(TARGET).cof
    $(COFFCONVERT) -O coff-avr $< $(TARGET).cof


extcoff: $(TARGET).elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_EXTENDED_COFF) $(TARGET).cof
    $(COFFCONVERT) -O coff-ext-avr $< $(TARGET).cof



# Create final output files (.hex, .eep) from ELF output file.
%.hex: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_FLASH) $@
    $(OBJCOPY) -O $(FORMAT) -R .eeprom -R .fuse -R .lock $< $@

%.eep: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_EEPROM) $@
    -$(OBJCOPY) -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom="alloc,load" \
    --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 --no-change-warnings -O $(FORMAT) $< $@ || exit 0

# Create extended listing file from ELF output file.
%.lss: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_EXTENDED_LISTING) $@
    $(OBJDUMP) -h -S -z $< > $@

# Create a symbol table from ELF output file.
%.sym: %.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_SYMBOL_TABLE) $@
    $(NM) -n $< > $@



# Create library from object files.
.SECONDARY : $(TARGET).a
.PRECIOUS : $(OBJ)
%.a: $(OBJ)
    @echo
    @echo $@
    @echo $(MSG_CREATING_LIBRARY) $@
    $(AR) $@ $(OBJ)


# Link: create ELF output file from object files.
.SECONDARY : $(TARGET).elf
.PRECIOUS : $(OBJ)
%.elf: $(OBJ)
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_LINKING) $@
    $(CC) $(ALL_CFLAGS) $^ --output $@ $(LDFLAGS)


# Compile: create object files from C source files.
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_COMPILING) $<
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 


# Compile: create object files from C++ source files.
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_COMPILING_CPP) $<
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@ 


# Compile: create assembler files from C source files.
%.s : %.c
    $(CC) -S $(ALL_CFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Compile: create assembler files from C++ source files.
%.s : %.cpp
    $(CC) -S $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Assemble: create object files from assembler source files.
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.S
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_ASSEMBLING) $<
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_ASFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Create preprocessed source for use in sending a bug report.
%.i : %.c
    $(CC) -E -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 


# Target: clean project.
clean: begin clean_list end

clean_list :
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_CLEANING)
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).hex
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).eep
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).cof
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).elf
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).map
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).sym
    $(REMOVE) $(TARGET).lss
    $(REMOVE) $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
    $(REMOVE) $(SRC:%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.lst)
    $(REMOVE) $(SRC:.c=.s)
    $(REMOVE) $(SRC:.c=.d)
    $(REMOVE) $(SRC:.c=.i)
    $(REMOVEDIR) .dep


# Create object files directory
$(shell mkdir $(OBJDIR) 2>/dev/null)


# Include the dependency files.
-include $(shell mkdir .dep 2>/dev/null) $(wildcard .dep/*)


# Listing of phony targets.
.PHONY : all begin finish end sizebefore sizeafter gccversion \
build elf hex eep lss sym coff extcoff \
clean clean_list program debug gdb-config
```

First of all I would like to apologize for the length of the code.

I've been getting errors in my Makefile stating that the "block", "robot", "basic", and "carrying" variables called in the constructors and in various methods in this source file have undefined references to their header file definitions
The errors are as follows:

```
IntermediateRobotFunctions.o: In function `IntermediateRobotFunctions::updateRobotData()':
C:\Users\Edward\CWork\BioloidAVR_/IntermediateRobotFunctions.cpp:74: undefined reference to `IntermediateRobotFunctions::carrying'
C:\Users\Edward\CWork\BioloidAVR_/IntermediateRobotFunctions.cpp:75: undefined reference to `IntermediateRobotFunctions::robot'
C:\Users\Edward\CWork\BioloidAVR_/IntermediateRobotFunctions.cpp:75: undefined reference to `IntermediateRobotFunctions::robot'
C:\Users\Edward\CWork\BioloidAVR_/IntermediateRobotFunctions.cpp:75: undefined reference to `IntermediateRobotFunctions::newNearest(Robot)'
```

where the above errors are repeated for all variables in every method of all of the following classes:

- BasicRobotFunctions
- IntermediateRobotFunctions
- AdvancedRobotFunctions
- Robot
- Block
- Structure

including on variables and methods received from pre-made source and header files imported from the Bioloid Embedded C API.

Again apologies for a long post possibly including a little irrelevant information but I wanted to give the complete picture; can anyone please tell me what's wrong and how I should go about fixing it?

Comment: You might want to look at these questions. Most likely there's a problem with the linker command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533787/undefined-reference-to-in-avr-gcc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785061/c-undefined-reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549526/undefined-references-to-functions-in-linked-avrfix-library-using-avr-gcc-compile

Comment: You posted the code of AdvancedRobotFunctions.hpp instead of IntermediateRobotFunctions.hpp

Comment: sorry jpo38, and thanks for the notice I just arranged it now.

I've already reviewed some other questions Brendan, for the most part the suggestions haven't worked - but I'll take a look at those hopefully they've got what I'm looking for

Comment: There does not appear to be a definition of `newNearest(Robot)` (only of `newNearest()`, nor of the declared static variables. It is not surprising that things that aren't there aren't found. Also: It's really odd to initialize static members in a constructor, although perhaps not as odd as having a class with only static members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
class IntermediateRobotFunctions {
public:
    static Block block;
    static Robot robot;
    static BasicRobotFunctions basic;
    static bool carrying;
```

where you have declared these variables to be `static`, but you have not put this:

```
Block IntermediateRobotFunctions::block;
Robot IntermediateRobotFunctions::robot;
BasicRobotFunctions IntermediateRobotFunctions::basic;
bool IntermediateRobotFunctions::carrying;
```

any place in your `.cpp` files, which means you have not actually defined (set aside actual memory for) those variables anywhere. That's what the compiler messages are telling you - the variables can't be found when it's trying to fix up all the various address links...